# Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW not working properly

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-transactions

I have the following scenario. 
     I have one transaction method which calls another transaction method which having REQUIRED_NEW Propagation. if the first method gets exception then the second method (REQUIRED_NEW Propagation) also rollbacks.

I am using JPA, Spring-boot and chainedKakfkaTransactionManager

I have tried with changing chainedKakfkaTransactionManager to default one still no luck

here is my code :

```
@Service
@Transactional(readOnly = false)
public class ComponentServiceImpl implements ComponentService {
@Autowired
private UserRepository userRepository ; 
@Override
@Transactional
public boolean validateName(String name) {
try{
  retrun userRepository.validate(name);  
  }catch(Exception e){
   handleError(name);
   throw new Exception("user not valid");
  }
}
@Override
@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public boolean handleError(String name) {
          userRepository.update(name);
}
}
```

Rollback is happening in the handleError method too. is there any code mistake?

Comment: Yes, Spring creates proxies around the class you're calling for items like `Transactional`, `Cachable` etc. Spring cannot proxy when you are already in the proxy class in this case.

Comment: @DarrenForsythe thanks for the quick reply. so should I create a new class or remove transaction annotation from class level

Comment: if you want a new transaction you could return from you `validateName` method and call the `handlerError` yourself to get a new transaction

Comment: Thanks, issue solved by autowiring the same bean.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @DarrenForsythe,

By Creating an autowire object for the same class (self-reference) its worked for me

```
    @Service
    @Transactional(readOnly = false)
    public class ComponentServiceImpl implements ComponentService {
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository ; 

// CREATE SELF REFRENCE
    @Autowired
    private ComponentService componentService;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public boolean validateName(String name) {
    try{
      retrun userRepository.validate(name);  
      }catch(Exception e){
       componentService.handleError(name);
       throw new Exception("user not valid");
      }
    }
    @Override
    @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public boolean handleError(String name) {
              userRepository.update(name);
    }
    }
```